# How to avoid an unnecessary round trip in cookie based authentication flow

Tags: authentication, cookies, oauth, single-page-application

My current project is a SPA consisting of React and Redux on the client side, and Node.js and express on the server side. I'm using passport.js to handle Oauth.

The current flow goes like this:

1) Visitor enter the site url, and we return our main.js bundle

2) After the application is booted up, can we call the backend ('/api/user/me') which either return our user state or nothing.

3) We can now determine if the user is logged in, and whether our app should show the 'public welcome page' or the 'private dashboard page'.

4) Finally, lazy load which page component the user is entitled to.

My question corresponds to section 2), as it seems like a kinda unnecessary round trip, when our visitors already is communicating with our backend in step 1).
After all, I only need to switch a single value inside Redux to show either the 'welcome' or 'dashboard' page. Furthermore does it block for 4), which make the loadtime even longer.

So how should I handle this back-and-forth scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In a presentation by an AuthO advocate, he mentioned that their cookie based authentication worked by having to communicate with the authentication servers. Except that they setup a quick iframe on the page that quickly queries their identity servers, validates the cookie, and if your authentication hasn't expired then they just refresh your token. You're good to go after that.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: How does it not?

Comment: This sounds like extra back and forth, not less.